How to convert heic format to jpeg format
The ffmpeg master branch already supports the heic format. How do I pass parameters using the ffmpeg command to convert heic images to jpeg images of other resolutions?
ffmpeg -i test.heic output.jpg, this command only transcodes part of the heic image；
ffmpeg -i test.heic -map 0 %d.jpeg, this command will generate 49 jpeg pictures.
But I don’t know how to synthesize a complete jpeg picture at once, and it has black borders (a multiple of 8, for example, the resolution of the 8th picture is wrong)

ffmpeg -i test.heic output.jpg, this command only transcodes part of the heic image；ffmpeg -i test.heic -map 0 %d.jpeg, this command will generate 49 jpeg pictures, but I don’t know how to synthesize a complete jpeg picture at once, and it has black borders (a multiple of 8, for example, the resolution of the 8th picture is wrong)

Any progress on this ? I am stuck in the same problem of tiled heics.

to convert a heic image to be able to view it as usual,
sudo apt-get install libheif-examples

then convert image to jpg:
heif-convert input.heic output.jpg

then view the image using any image viewer - here's an example:
ristretto  output.jpg

this works on debian-derived systems including ubuntu

This doesn‘t answer how to do it in ffmpeg
